# processing requests when we have multiple requests from multiple customers

Tags: node.js, rest, heroku, architecture

I'm developing node service on heroku platform , this service will accept requests from different clients but can process only 10 requests at a time.
After receiving request we will write into database then process 10 at a time.
when multiple sends requests to this service and I want to split the threads equally among customers. for example customer A sends 10k  requests , B sends 5K requests and C sends 100 requests.

1. We need to split threads for 3 customers equally.
   2.After completing customer C requests , I want to allocate threads available equally to A and B.
   3.After B completion , only to A.
2. If we receive requests for any other customers , we need to split threads.
   Can anyone help me to write this algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Basically you are looking for load balancing, right?

Comment: So rather than load-balancing requests, you want to load-balance clients so that the throughput is consistent for each client? I.e. time taken for N requests with M clients with active requests will be something like (N*M)/(10*t)? And that the first client doesn't dominate?

Do the clients send the requests individually? or in batches (of 10k, 5k & 100 in your example)?

Is the goal that for any client, a single request will be handled asap, but for multiple concurrent requests, priority is given to single requests from other clients over the second+ requests from this client?

Answer (score 0):

In node JS we can use `process environment variable`. Using process Env variable you can identify how many ports should be used by one process and if more request you will get you can decrease the variable value and if some process completed then you can increase the variable value.

```
process.env.variable_name = 'Value';
```

You can access this value in any process and update in any process. Value for this process always the same for all process.

```
console.log(process.env.variable_name);
```